# How to keep a hidden div from disappearing after leaving the first element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have [JSFiddle code here](https://jsfiddle.net/eliluong/5ht3w39d/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".dateadded").hover(
      function() {
        $dateadded = $(this);
        $content = $dateadded.next();
        $content.slideToggle(50);
      }, function() {
        $dateadded = $(this);
        $content = $dateadded.next();
        $content.slideToggle(30);
      });
});
```

Code is working as expected. infobox_content is the div that contains content to be revealed. I want it so when the cursor moves from dateadded div (the trigger), and moves to infobox_content, the div does not disappear again, until they leave either div. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you all. I took keul's solution to produce similar code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the events management to the wrapper:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".infobox").hover(
      function() {
        $dateadded = $(this).find('.dateadded');
        $content = $dateadded.next();
        $content.slideToggle(50);
      }, function() {
        $dateadded = $(this);
        $content = $dateadded.next();
        $content.slideToggle(30);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place your `infobox_content` box in parent `dateadded` box not after, by that why when you leave both divs `infobox_content` will disappear

Like this:

```
<div class="infobox">
 <div class="dateadded">
  2015-12-18 22:09:09
  <div class="infobox_content" style="display: none;">
    <div class="infobox_comments">Comments go here</div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Also you need to change `infobox_content` select part in your js hover definition

```
$(".dateadded").hover(
  function() {
    $dateadded = $(this);
    $content = $dateadded.find('.infobox_content'); // Here
    $content.slideToggle(50);
  }, function() {
    $dateadded = $(this);
    $content = $dateadded.find('.infobox_content'); // and Here
    $content.slideToggle(30);
  });
});
```

Here is updated jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/5ht3w39d/1/

Answer (score 0):

Bind events to container and you could use `in/out` hover method handler:

***Tip:*** don't declare variable globally, using `var` statement

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".infobox").hover(function(e) {
      var $content = $(this).children('.infobox_content');
      $content.slideToggle(e.type === "mouseenter" ? 50 : 30);
    });
});
```

[### -jsFiddle-](https://jsfiddle.net/5ht3w39d/2/)

That's said, you could use CSS only solution instead:

```
.infobox .infobox_content {
  padding-top: 5px;
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;  
  transition: height 300ms; 
}
.infobox:hover .infobox_content{
  height: 1.2em; 
}
```

[### -jsFiddle-](https://jsfiddle.net/5ht3w39d/3/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't know you could do it with CSS, I'll try that next time. You noted "don't declare variable globally, using var." Do you mean to use var $content instead of just $content?

Answer (score 0):

Aa answer is to use the container div of both elements. Try [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ht3w39d/6/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(".infobox").hover(
  function() {
    $dateadded = $('.dateadded');
    $content = $dateadded.next();
    $content.slideToggle(50);
  });

});
```

Also don't forget to check w3schools when it is for learning.